# Elements of a multicanvas in different sizes?

Tags: python

Is there a posibility to get in a 3 by 2 canvas the pictures or plots in the one colum bigger than in the other? I want to have a big picture in the first column and some smaller histograms in the second column.

I tried setting diffrend sizes for the figure but this just changes all of the figures.